# Using strings of decimals in python

Tags: python, string, decimal

I'm trying to use a string of a decimal, but I am getting an unwanted "0.".  For example:

```
age = .01
print 'test%s'%(age)
print 'test' + str(age)
```

These both return 'test0.01', but I want 'test.01'.  I know there is a simple solution.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
age = .01
print 'test%s' % str(age)[1:] if 0<age<1 else str(age)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (with the conditional statement), though you do have a typo with a single quote instead of a paren around age.  Thanks!

Comment: Fails for `x` such that `-1 < x < 0`.

Comment: it is not specified what he want in those cases -.01 doesn't seems be a sensible answer in my opinion

Answer (score 6):

```
age = .01
print 'test' + str(age).lstrip('0')
```

Works for `age > 1.0` as well.

Comment: The question doesn't actually say age is always positive, so it might matter that it doesn't work for `-1 < age < 0`. Then again it may not.

Comment: That would give strange answer if age = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
age = .01
print 'test' + (str(age)[1:] if 0 < age < 1 else str(age))
```

Comment: Note: fails for `x` outside of `0 < x < 1`. Safe: replace `"0"` with `""` if followed by `"."` and not preceded by a digit (easy with regexp: lookahead and negative lookbehind). Or just use this, for numbers between 0 and 1, and a similar action for numbers between -1 and 0.

Comment: That will break for ages > 1.

Comment: No, but presumably he also wants an answer that works for more than just the exact number given (for example, the lstrip()-based one).  If you only want an answer that works for the example given, "print 'test .01'" will do...

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying that he said his problem was an unwanted '0'.  I mean this code doesn't work if `age = five` either.  I'm not claiming to have put forward the greatest python code ever written, just trying to give him something to work with.

Comment: @BenH: Sorry - to clarify, I commented at the time when you did not have the `if` yet. This fixes it for positive numbers; `-1 < x < 0` still won't work (although the solution is simple and analogous, and just an additional `if` away).

Comment: I guess my main point is that it's not clear what is supposed to happen for negative numbers or numbers larger than 1, because that isn't specified in the post.  Sure, we could check for all of this, but should we also check that age isn't a string, or a list, etc.?